# Navigator - Drawbacks of pop() and memory concerns for push()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

**The question here is much more in-depth than the title, if you can re-word it better, feel free to edit.**

In my application there's a lot of different pages where I need to switch between showing and hiding the `NavigationBar` component. I'm using `Redux` to manage my application state and using `componentWillMount()` to send a dispatch saying that the page had loaded to enable or disable the status-bar through a variable passed as a prop to the NavigationBar instance.

To give you a quick (and messy) example of this, check the code below:

```
const CustomNavigationBar = connect( (state) => {
    return {
        navigationBarHidden: state.navigationReducer.navigationBarHidden
    }
})(React.createClass({
  render() {
    if (this.props.navigationBarHidden) {
      return null;
    }
    return <Navigator.NavigationBar {...this.props} />
  }
}))
```

This method is working besides for a few cases when I want to use `pop()`. While `pop()` will unmount the current route, the previous route stays mounted in memory, so when going back to a page through using `pop()` the `componentWillMount()` function is never invoked.

I thought to myself, alright so I'll just use `resetTo(...)` however it turns out that while this fires `componentWillMount()` again, there is no transition between the pages.

This brought me to `replacePreviousAndPop(...)` which did what I wanted, kind-of. It replace and reset the previous route which called `componentWillMount()` again, however it went to show that the `connect()` function was called multiple times during this process instead of once, meaning the component was loaded more than once during navigation.

So, this brings me to `push(...)` which transitions like you're moving forward and not backwards, but makes me worry about memory as the previous routes are never unmounted. Doesn't this mean that there will be multiple instances of each route and memory usage will increase with every time a user navigates?

Perhaps I'm missing something really important here, but the over-all goal is to call a function that changes the state when the page is brought into view. Not on every re-render. `componentWillMount()` does a great job of this, until navigation is involved.

Obviously there's some hacks I can use here, but I can't believe that there's no way to do this from the Navigator itself.

**EDIT: ** @DavinTryon proposed checking out `componentWillUpdate()` however it is also not called when you `pop()` the current route from teh stack, even if the component you call `componentWillUpdate()` is the one loaded as a result of the `pop()`

**EDIT2:** David's earlier comment made me think about the `componentWillReceiveProps()` method considering `redux-react` add props to the component through the `connect()` feature. It turns out that this is also not fired when you `pop()` the current route

---

Ideas for "hacking" this include a class-level variable that states rather or not the onLoaded dispatch should be sent. (`var dispatchRequired`) This variable would be checked in the `render()` function and `dispatch()` would be called if necessary. `dispatchRequired` would be set to false before `dispatch()` was sent, just as a failsafe to protect from infinite loops, when navigating away dispatchRequired would be set to true, that way on next render it will call the method again. Example:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.dispatchRequired = true
    }

    navigateAway() {
        this.dispatchRequired = true
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'next-controller'
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.dispatchRequired) {
            this.dispatchRequired = false
            this.props.sendDispatch()
        }

        return <TouchableHighlight onPressed={this.navigateAway.bind(this)}> ... </TouchableHighlight>
    }
}

export default connect( (connect) => {
    return {}
}, (dispatch) => {
    return {
        sendDispatch: () => dispatch({'PAGE_LOADED', payload: {hideNavigation: true}})
    }
})(Example)
```

---

**EDIT3: THIS HACK WILL NOT WORK**.  Turns out the `render()` function is never called when `pop()` ing back to the previous route, I would assume this is because react has not detected any state changes, so the `render()` method never needs to be called.

---

**EDIT4: A new hack**

So here's a new hack that I came up with, and it works, but it's quite annoying. Basically in your `mapDispatchToProps` callback in the `connect()` function you manually send the dispatch after a timeout. Extremely hacky, but works.

```
export default connect( (state) => {
    return {}
}, (dispatch) => {
    return {
        gotoNext: (navigator) => {
            navigator.push({
                id: 'next-component'
            })
            setTimeout(()=>dispatch({type: PAGE_LOADED, payload: {hideNavigation: true}), 400)
        }
    }
})(Example)
```

Comment: Have you experimented with adding a `componetWillUpdate` as well?

Comment: @DavinTryon - I have not, because of the line from the documentation `"This method is not called for the initial render."` however, perhaps using it in conjunction with `componentWillMount()` will yield appropriate results. I'll test it out and edit.

Comment: @DavinTryon - `componentWillUpdate()` is not called after `pop()` -- This is also the case with `componentWillReceiveProps()` even though the `connect()` function injects props from the redux store

Comment: Are you asking "how does a component know when it has reached the top of the view stack after all children have been popped"?

Comment: @pomo, perhaps that's an appropriate question.